# Post form with a file upload by Ajax on Button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input, bootstrap-4

This is my form. In this form I have some text boxes and a file upload to upload an image and send it to back end. I want send the image data and text box data same time once user click on the save button.

```
<form id="profileModalForm" name="profileModalForm" onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off" >
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row margin-top10 text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                            <input id="hiddenIdTxt" type="text" name="hiddenIdTxt" class="display-none" value="<%=user.getId()%>"/>

                            <div class="row margin-top10">
                                <img class="img-responsive" style="display:block; margin:auto;" alt="<%out.println(user.getUsername());%>" 
                                src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%out.println(user.getEmployee().getProfilePicture());%>" height='200' width='200'>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row" style="display:block; margin:auto;">
                                <p><b><%= user.getEmployee().getFullName()%></b></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row form-group margin-top10">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 margin-top10">
                                    <label style="text-align: left; float: left;" class="control-label">New Password</label>
                                    <input id="passwordTxt" name ="passwordTxt" class="form-control"  maxlength="20" placeholder="(Optional)"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>     

                            <div class="row form-group margin-top10">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 margin-top10">
                                    <label style="text-align: left; float: left;" class="control-label">Repeat New Password</label>
                                    <input id="repeatPasswordTxt" name ="repeatPasswordTxt" class="form-control"  maxlength="20" placeholder="(Optional)"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>   
                             <div class="row form-group">
                                 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 margin-top10">
                                    <label style="text-align: left; float: left;" class="control-label">File input</label>
                                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" id="inputFile" name="inputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                                </div>
                             </div>              

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" onclick="saveProfileEditBtn();">Save changes</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

On Submit button click event I call a ajax function to upload form data.

```
function saveProfileEditBtn() {
    var data = $('#profileModalForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'SaveProfileModalData.ws',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,        
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#notificationArea').html(html);
        }
    }
    );
}
```

But event I select a image in file upload it does to post its data. What I see in browser console's parameters is

```
hiddenIdTxt=1000&passwordTxt=abcd&repeatPasswordTxt=abcd
```

How can I send the selected image data using a ajax post? Im using jquery and bootstrap. My back end is java + struts.

Comment: your `input` for file has no name

Comment: I have changed the input to 
<input id="fileInput" name ="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" id="inputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">

but still it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is not the `id`. Is the `name`. If your `input` has no attribute `name`, it won't be passed with the data of the form

Comment: I added it. Still doesnt work. ( name ="fileInput" ). My console still shows the same data as before (hiddenIdTxt=1000&passwordTxt=343&repeatPasswordTxt=434).

Comment: try to not serialize the form, and look what is the `html` received on the `success`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to post the multi-part form through ajax.

Try to get the form data

```
 var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

 var formdata = new FormData(form);
```

Set `processData: false`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "--Post url here--",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,  // Important!
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not serialize the form
Use this in your data: new FormData(this);
also change your code to $("#profileModalForm").on('submit', function()) follow with the rest, dont assign anything to variable